# How to get a $scope value inside a function with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a pagination code which I should use repeatedly inside the same controller and thought of putting it inside a function. But it is not working as I expected. Always sends an error saying some value is undefined.

How do I achieve this.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('efutures.hr.controllers.creation', [])
        .controller('UserCreateController', UserCreateController);

    UserCreateController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', '$http', 'deptService', 'DeptNameService','EmployeeService'];

    function UserCreateController($scope, $location, $rootScope, $http, deptService, DeptNameService, EmployeeService) {

        (function initController() {
            deptService.getdepts(function (res) {

                $scope.depts = JSON.parse(res.data);
            });

            EmployeeService.GetEmpDetails(function (res) {
                $scope.FilterDetails = JSON.parse(res.data);   //This is the variable that I need inside the function.            

                $scope.PaginationTrigger($scope.FilterDetails); //CODE APPLIED HERE

            });
        })();

        $scope.reset = function () {

            $('#depts').val('').trigger('change.select2');
            EmployeeService.GetEmpDetails(function (res) {
                $scope.FilterDetails = JSON.parse(res.data);
            });
        };

        $scope.paginationTrigger =function(details){ //This method is used to control the pagination
             $scope.nums = ["10", "20", "30"];
                $scope.viewBy = $scope.nums[0];
                $scope.totalEmployees = $scope.details.length;
                $scope.currentPage = 1;
                $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.viewBy;
                $scope.maxSize = 5;

                $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
                    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
                };

                $scope.pageChanged = function () {
                    console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
                }

                $scope.setEmployeesPerPage = function (num) {
                    $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
                    $scope.currentPage = 1;
                }
        }

        $scope.DropdownSelected = function (value) {
            console.log(value.DeptName + ' Selected');

            var DeptNameChanged = {
                'Name': value
            };

            DeptNameService.DeptNameValue(DeptNameChanged, function (res) {

                $scope.FilterDetails = JSON.parse(res.data);

                $scope.PaginationTrigger($scope.FilterDetails); //CODE APPLIED HERE

            });


        };
    }
})();
```

> According to the above code the ERROR IS: angular.js:13642 TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

So how can I achieve this? help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: try `$scope[details].length`

Comment: You haven't defined $scope.details anywhere, you only received details (not $scope.details, regular details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.This is what I tried to accomplish and it was successful. Special thanks to @Sravan for repeatedly trying to help me out. Also thank you all for you help.

So here's the code. Thought of sharing for learning.

```
//Create a function in the controller
function paginationTrigger(value) {

    $scope.nums = ["10", "20", "30"];
    $scope.viewBy = $scope.nums[0];
    $scope.totalEmployees = value.length;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.viewBy;
    $scope.maxSize = 5;

    $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };

    $scope.pageChanged = function () {
        console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
    }

    $scope.setEmployeesPerPage = function (num) {
        $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
    }
}

/* Call the function in the desired palce.
In this case inside my service function  */

EmployeeService.GetEmpDetails(function (res) {
    $scope.FilterDetails = JSON.parse(res.data);
    //pagination code
    paginationTrigger($scope.FilterDetails); //Passing the value

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
test = {"a" : 1}
details = "a"
alert(test[details])
```

Use, `$scope[details].length` since `details` is a parameter there.

```
$scope.paginationTrigger =function(details){ //This method is used to control the pagination
         $scope.nums = ["10", "20", "30"];
            $scope.viewBy = $scope.nums[0];
            $scope.totalEmployees = $scope[details].length;
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
            $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.viewBy;
            $scope.maxSize = 5;

            $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
                $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
            };

            $scope.pageChanged = function () {
                console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
            }

            $scope.setEmployeesPerPage = function (num) {
                $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
                $scope.currentPage = 1;
            }
    }
```

Pls look the code snippet, you will get the error.

Comment: you sent `($scope.FilterDetails)` into  `paginationTrigger` where you are getting error right?

Comment: you are trying to do `$scope.details` but you cannot refer the parameter you sent directly using `.` notation.

Comment: @Sravan Nope didn't work. This works fine without the function. Inside `EmployeeService.GetEmpDetails`

Comment: SInce I want to apply every code which relates to the pagination I thought I put inside a function.

Comment: just check what is in details `console.log(details)`

Comment: How do I get `$scope.FilterDetails` inside `$scope.paginationTrigger()` function

Comment: @Sravan nothing it just a local parameter for this function. I used `$scope.details` outside the function as a global variable but not working.

Comment: @Sravan $scope.Filterdetails is a JSON string.

Comment: `JSON.parse($scope[details]).length`, try this

Comment: @Sravan nope didn't work. Why can you explain you're using `[details]` ?